# Positioning of a static element

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, grid, ionic3

I'm trying to put my search bar on top, right now:

As you see in the image below my search is at the bottom. What I try to do is place in the top, under the toolbar.

[image]

**This is my css:**

```
.buscador {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
        width: 90%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: .9;
    }
```

Comment: What did you try, and why did it not work? Also... could the word `bottom` have anything to do with it being positioned from the `bottom`? (hint hint hint)

Comment: @Roy Prins hace I want to move only the input-search for the top,
Not the blue buttons they do not

Comment: This is no way to ask a question and I frankly helped you more than I should have. First use google and provide an example of what you have tried and specify why that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using [**Ionic grid**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid/) and [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You can design layout as shown below:

*.scss*

```
.home {

    scroll-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    ion-grid {
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .row1 {
        flex: 1;
    }

     .row2 {
        flex:9;
    }

}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content class="home">

    <ion-grid>

      <ion-row style="background-color: #e74c3c;" class="row1">
        <ion-col>Your search bar</ion-col>
      </ion-row>

     <ion-row style="background-color: #f1c40f;" class="row2">
       <ion-col>Map details</ion-col>
     </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

[**Plunker is here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKS6Jd?p=preview)

[**Nice article about the layout design**](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-look-at-the-grid-system-in-ionic-2/)